# Latex, oblivoir class: make index with hyperlink

Tags: lists, indexing, hyperlink, oblivoir

I want to make index list with hyperlink.
The LaTeX code is:

```
\documentclass{oblivoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}%
\makeindex

\begin{document}
    
\section{Introduction}
In this example several keywords\index{keywords} will be used 
which are important and deserve to appear in the Index\index{Index}.

Terms like generate\index{generate} and some\index{others} will 
also show up. 

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Another package is ok, but failed only for oblivoir class. I want to jump to corresponding page when clicking a item at Index page.